# Does transaction.atomic roll back increments to a pk sequence

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using Django 2.2 and my question is: **does [transaction.atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/) roll back increments to a pk sequence**?

Below is the background bug I wrote up that led me to this issue

---

I'm facing a really weird issue that I can't figure out and I'm hoping someone has faced a similar issue.

An insert using the django ORM `.create()` function is returning `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(5795) already exists.`

Fine. But then I look at the table and no record with id=5795 exists!

`SELECT * from my_table where id=5795;`
shows `(0 rows)`

A look at the sequence `my_table_id_seq` shows that it has nonetheless incremented to show `last_value = 5795` as if the above record was inserted. **Moreover the issue does not always occur.** A successful insert with different data is inserted at **id=5796**. (I tried reset the pk sequence but that didn't do anything, since it doesnt seem to be the problem anyway)

I'm quite stumped by this and it has caused us a lot of issues on one specific table. Finally I realize the call is wrapped in `transaction.atomic` and that a particular scenario may be causing a double insert with the same `pk`.

So my theory is: The transaction atomic is not rolling back the increment of the

Comment: It would not make sense for a transaction to rollback the sequence, what if the transaction takes a long time to commit and another insert happens, what ID should the second insert take and how would a rollback affect it?

Comment: A PostgreSQL sequence won't produce this error. It seems your app library (django in this case) is getting "creative" and doing something else behind the scenes.

Comment: When you look `my_table_id_seq` it is also important to look at the value in the `is_called` field. Where `t` means the next number used will be greater then the `last_value` and `'f` means `last_value` will be used. To get a usable answer you will need to provide the code that is happening in the `transaction.atomic`. Add as update to your question.

Comment: I should have added Postgres sequences do not roll back. Every time they are touched by a statement they advance whether the statement succeeds or not. In addition to the code in the `transaction.atomic` the model that is being worked on would be a good thing to add to the question.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver your answer solves it for me because if what you say is true then I know what in my code is causing this (so will keep it in scope by excluding that part). Would you mind writing an answer with the above and with your understanding of why it doesnt roll back and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres sequences do not roll back. Every time they are touched by a statement they advance whether the statement succeeds or not. For more information see Notes section here [Create Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html).